# Multiple JS slideshows on one page

Tags: javascript, html

I have 3 slide shows I want to display on one page. The problem is at the moment is that instead of each slideShow changing image one by one. The last slide show is changing by 3 and the other 2 are doing nothing.

```js
var slideShows = document.getElementsByClassName("slideShow");
var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
var timers = [];
var slideShowsArray = [];

function addListener(element, listenFor, functionToCall) {
 for (var i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {

  element[i].addEventListener(listenFor, functionToCall);
 }
}

function addDots() {
 for (var i = 0; i < slideShows.length; i++) {
  var slides = slideShows[i].getElementsByClassName("slide");
  for (var j = 0; j < slides.length; j++) {
   var dot = document.createElement("div");
   dot.classList.add("dot");
   dot.innerHTML = "O";
   slideShows[i].appendChild(dot);
  }
 }
}

addDots();

function nextSlide(ele) {
 var elem = document.getElementById(ele);
 console.log(ele);
 var currentSlideHere = elem.getElementsByClassName("visible");
 var dots = elem.getElementsByClassName("dot");
 var slides = elem.getElementsByClassName("slide");
 var slidesArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(slides);
 var here = slidesArray.indexOf(currentSlideHere[0]);
 dots[here].style.backgroundColor = "white";
 slides[here].classList.remove("visible");
 here += 1;
 if (here >= slides.length) {
  here = 0;
 }
 slides[here].classList.add("visible");
 dots[here].style.backgroundColor = "grey";
}

function changeImageDot() {
 var slides = this.parentElement.getElementsByClassName("slide");
 var dotsHere = this.parentElement.getElementsByClassName("dot");
 var dotsArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(dotsHere);
 var chosenSlide = dotsArray.indexOf(this);
 for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
  slides[i].classList.remove("visible");
  dotsHere[i].style.backgroundColor = "white";
 }
 this.style.backgroundColor = "grey";
 slides[chosenSlide].classList.add("visible");
}

addListener(dots, "click", changeImageDot);

addListener(slideShows, "mouseover", function () {
 var thisIndex = slideShowsArray.indexOf(this.id);
 clearInterval(timers[thisIndex]);
})


addListener(slideShows, "mouseleave", function () {
 var thisIndex = slideShowsArray.indexOf(this.id);
 if (thisIndex == 0) {

 } else if (thisIndex == 1) {

 }
})

function setUpTimers() {
 for (var i = 0; i < slideShows.length; i++) {
  slideShowsArray.push(slideShows[i].id);
  var element = slideShowsArray[i];
  var timer = setInterval(function(){nextSlide(element)}, 5000);
  timers.push(timer);
 }
 console.log(timers);
 console.log(slideShowsArray);
}

setUpTimers();
```

```css
.slideDiv {
 height: 200px;
 width: 200px;
 background-color: #378B53;
}
.slide {
 display: none;
 transition: 4s;
}

.visible {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 opacity: 100;
}

.slideShow {
 width: 40%;
 display: inline-block;
}

.dot {
 display: inline-block;
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
 <div class = "slideShow" id = "slideShow1">
  <div class = "slideDiv slide visible">HELLO 1</div>
  <div class = "slideDiv slide">HELLO 2</div>
  <div class = "slideDiv slide">HELLO 3</div>
  <div class = "slideDiv slide">HELLO 4</div>
  <div class = "slideDiv slide">HELLO 3</div>
  <div class = "slideDiv slide">HELLO 4</div>
  <div class = "slideDiv slide">HELLO 3</div>
  <div class = "slideDiv slide">HELLO 4</div>
 </div>
  
   <div class = "slideShow" id = "slideShow2">
  <div class = "slideDiv slide visible">HELLO 1</div>
  <div class = "slideDiv slide">HELLO 2</div>
  <div class = "slideDiv slide">HELLO 3</div>
  <div class = "slideDiv slide">HELLO 4</div>
  <div class = "slideDiv slide">HELLO 3</div>
  <div class = "slideDiv slide">HELLO 4</div>
  <div class = "slideDiv slide">HELLO 3</div>
  <div class = "slideDiv slide">HELLO 4</div>
 </div>
  
   <div class = "slideShow" id = "slideShow3">
  <div class = "slideDiv slide visible">HELLO 1</div>
  <div class = "slideDiv slide">HELLO 2</div>
  <div class = "slideDiv slide">HELLO 3</div>
  <div class = "slideDiv slide">HELLO 4</div>
  <div class = "slideDiv slide">HELLO 3</div>
  <div class = "slideDiv slide">HELLO 4</div>
  <div class = "slideDiv slide">HELLO 3</div>
  <div class = "slideDiv slide">HELLO 4</div>
 </div>
```

As I hover over each slideshow a timer gets stopped.

Can someone please help with this, I am not sure where it is going wrong and it is quite frustrating.

Comment: Give an id to each slideshow. Then make an associative array of timers, dynamically using the slideshow IDs as key. Then start/clear that item/timer in timers array only.

Comment: Could you give an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to do it another way, instead of clearing the intervals and trying to restart them by creating new ones. Which ended up being very messy.

I am now just changing classes when I hover on the image which stops the slideshow function, because the slideshow is looking for the class "visible" and while the image is hovered over that class is removed.

See here:

```js
var slideShows = document.getElementsByClassName("slideShow");
var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
var slideShow1 = document.getElementById("slideShow1");
var slideShow1Timer = slideShow1.getAttribute("data-slide-time")
var slideShow2 = document.getElementById("slideShow2");
var slideShow2Timer = slideShow2.getAttribute("data-slide-time")
var slideShow3 = document.getElementById("slideShow3");
var slideShow3Timer = slideShow3.getAttribute("data-slide-time")
var timer1 = setInterval(function() {
  nextSlide("slideShow1")
}, slideShow1Timer);
var timer2 = setInterval(function() {
  nextSlide("slideShow2")
}, slideShow2Timer);
var timer3 = setInterval(function() {
  nextSlide("slideShow3")
}, slideShow3Timer);
var slideShowsArray = ["slideShow1", "slideShow2", "slideShow3"];

// Finds all elements by class name and adds an event listener to each.
function addListener(element, listenFor, functionToCall) {
  for (var i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {

    element[i].addEventListener(listenFor, functionToCall);
  }
}

function addDots() {
  for (var i = 0; i < slideShows.length; i++) {
    var slides = slideShows[i].getElementsByClassName("slide");
    for (var j = 0; j < slides.length; j++) {
      var dot = document.createElement("div");
      dot.classList.add("dot");
      dot.innerHTML = "O";
      slideShows[i].appendChild(dot);
    }
  }
}

addDots();

function nextSlide(ele) {
  var elem = document.getElementById(ele);
  var currentSlideHere = elem.getElementsByClassName("visible");
  if (currentSlideHere[0]) {
    var dots = elem.getElementsByClassName("dot");
    var slides = elem.getElementsByClassName("slide");
    var slidesArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(slides);
    var here = slidesArray.indexOf(currentSlideHere[0]);
    dots[here].style.backgroundColor = "white";
    slides[here].classList.remove("visible");
    here += 1;
    if (here >= slides.length) {
      here = 0;
    }
    slides[here].classList.add("visible");
    dots[here].style.backgroundColor = "grey";
  }
}

function changeImageDot() {
  var slides = this.parentElement.getElementsByClassName("slide");
  var dotsHere = this.parentElement.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  var dotsArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(dotsHere);
  var chosenSlide = dotsArray.indexOf(this);
  for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].classList.remove("visible");
    slides[i].classList.remove("visiblePaused");
    dotsHere[i].style.backgroundColor = "white";
  }
  this.style.backgroundColor = "grey";
  slides[chosenSlide].classList.add("visible");
}

addListener(dots, "click", changeImageDot);

addListener(slideShows, "mouseover", function() {
  var lemon = this.getElementsByClassName("visible");
  lemon[0].classList.add("visiblePaused");
  lemon[0].classList.remove("visible");
})


addListener(slideShows, "mouseleave", function() {
  var lemon = this.getElementsByClassName("visiblePaused");
  lemon[0].classList.add("visible");
  lemon[0].classList.remove("visiblePaused");
})
```

```css
.slideDiv {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #378B53;
}

.slide {
  display: none;
  transition: 4s;
}

.visible {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 100;
}

.visiblePaused {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 100;
}

.slideShow {
  width: 40%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dot {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="slideShow" id="slideShow1" data-slide-time="2000">
  <div class="slideDiv slide">HELLO 1</div>
  <div class="slideDiv slide">HELLO 2</div>
  <div class="slideDiv slide">HELLO 3</div>
  <div class="slideDiv slide visible">HELLO 4</div>
  <div class="slideDiv slide">HELLO 3</div>
  <div class="slideDiv slide">HELLO 4</div>
  <div class="slideDiv slide">HELLO 3</div>
  <div class="slideDiv slide">HELLO 4</div>
</div>
<div class="slideShow" id="slideShow2" data-slide-time="2000">
  <div class="slideDiv slide">HELLO 1</div>
  <div class="slideDiv slide">HELLO 2</div>
  <div class="slideDiv slide">HELLO 3</div>
  <div class="slideDiv slide visible">HELLO 4</div>
  <div class="slideDiv slide">HELLO 3</div>
  <div class="slideDiv slide">HELLO 4</div>
  <div class="slideDiv slide">HELLO 3</div>
  <div class="slideDiv slide">HELLO 4</div>
</div>
<div class="slideShow" id="slideShow3" data-slide-time="2000">
  <div class="slideDiv slide">HELLO 1</div>
  <div class="slideDiv slide">HELLO 2</div>
  <div class="slideDiv slide">HELLO 3</div>
  <div class="slideDiv slide visible">HELLO 4</div>
  <div class="slideDiv slide">HELLO 3</div>
  <div class="slideDiv slide">HELLO 4</div>
  <div class="slideDiv slide">HELLO 3</div>
  <div class="slideDiv slide">HELLO 4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this : https://jsfiddle.net/AnuragSinha/caqmhnt1/40/ I have fixed the mouseleave part. Now when you hover over a box, timer for that will start, others will wait for their respective mouseleave event. You may want to make similar changes as other places. Since we are working in a loop, notice how the value of loop variable 'i' is passed to the function.

```js
var slideShows = document.getElementsByClassName("slideShow");
var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
var timers = [];

// Finds all elements by class name and adds an event listener to each.
function addListener(element, listenFor, functionToCall) {
  for (var i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
    element[i].addEventListener(listenFor, functionToCall);
  }
}

function listen(element, listenFor, functionToCall) {
  element.addEventListener(listenFor, functionToCall);
}

function addDots() {
  for (var i = 0; i < slideShows.length; i++) {
    var slides = slideShows[i].getElementsByClassName("slide");
    for (var j = 0; j < slides.length; j++) {
      var dot = document.createElement("div");
      dot.classList.add("dot");
      dot.innerHTML = "O";
      slideShows[i].appendChild(dot);
    }
  }
}

addDots();

function nextSlide(i){
 console.log(i);
    var currentSlideHere = slideShows[i].getElementsByClassName("visible");
    var dots = slideShows[i].getElementsByClassName("dot");
    var slides = slideShows[i].getElementsByClassName("slide");
    var slidesArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(slides);
    var here = slidesArray.indexOf(currentSlideHere[0]);
    dots[here].style.backgroundColor = "white";
    slides[here].classList.remove("visible");
    here += 1;
    if (here >= slides.length) {
      here = 0;
    }
    slides[here].classList.add("visible");
    dots[here].style.backgroundColor = "grey";
}

function changeImageDot() {
  var slides = this.parentElement.getElementsByClassName("slide");
  var dotsHere = this.parentElement.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  var dotsArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(dotsHere);
  var chosenSlide = dotsArray.indexOf(this);
  for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].classList.remove("visible");
    dotsHere[i].style.backgroundColor = "white";
  }
  this.style.backgroundColor = "grey";
  slides[chosenSlide].classList.add("visible");
}

addListener(dots, "click", changeImageDot);

for(var i=0; i<slideShows.length; i++) {
 (function() {
  console.log("Add mousover for " + i);
  console.log(slideShows[i]);
  var count = i;
    listen(slideShows[count], "mouseover", function() {
      console.log("mouseover : " + count);
      clearInterval(timers[count]);
      timers[count] = undefined;
    })
  }());
}


for(var i=0; i<slideShows.length; i++) {
 (function() {
  var count = i;
  timers.push(undefined);
  console.log("Add mouse leave for " + i);
  console.log(slideShows[count]);
    listen(slideShows[count], "mouseleave", function() {
    console.log("mouseleave : " + count);
  slideShow(count);
})
  }());
 
}


function slideShow(count) {
console.log("slideShow..start " + count);
console.log("slideShow..start " + timers[count]);
if(timers[count] == undefined ) {
 console.log("proceed");
 timers[count] = setInterval(function() {nextSlide(count)},   1000);
} 
}
```

```css
.slide {
  display: none;
  transition: 4s;
}

.visible {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 100;
}

.slideShow {
  width: 40%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.slideDiv {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #378B53;
}

.dot {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="slideShow" id="1">
  <div class="slideDiv slide visible">HELLO 1</div>
  <div class="slideDiv slide">HELLO 2</div>
  <div class="slideDiv slide">HELLO 3</div>
  <div class="slideDiv slide">HELLO 4</div>
  <div class="slideDiv slide">HELLO 3</div>
  <div class="slideDiv slide">HELLO 4</div>
  <div class="slideDiv slide">HELLO 3</div>
  <div class="slideDiv slide">HELLO 4</div>
</div>

<div class="slideShow" id="2">
  <div class="slideDiv slide visible">HELLO 1</div>
  <div class="slideDiv slide">HELLO 2</div>
  <div class="slideDiv slide">HELLO 3</div>
  <div class="slideDiv slide">HELLO 4</div>
  <div class="slideDiv slide">HELLO 3</div>
  <div class="slideDiv slide">HELLO 4</div>
  <div class="slideDiv slide">HELLO 3</div>
  <div class="slideDiv slide">HELLO 4</div>
</div>

<div class="slideShow" id="3">
  <div class="slideDiv slide visible">HELLO 1</div>
  <div class="slideDiv slide">HELLO 2</div>
  <div class="slideDiv slide">HELLO 3</div>
  <div class="slideDiv slide">HELLO 4</div>
  <div class="slideDiv slide">HELLO 3</div>
  <div class="slideDiv slide">HELLO 4</div>
  <div class="slideDiv slide">HELLO 3</div>
  <div class="slideDiv slide">HELLO 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Shemiroth : Refer updated link, try mouseout on the containers.

Comment: Hmm it seems that everytime mouse out happens it is adding another setInterval which just makes the slides faster....

Comment: I think nextSlide is getting invoked multiple times for every mouseleave. But above was some quick code changes to help you through. I am sure you will be able to take it from here. If you have some specific questions do let me know, will be happy to help.

Comment: Anyways, I have fixed it , refer it at https://jsfiddle.net/AnuragSinha/caqmhnt1/40 
Updated the answer too